# How do I change the active <li> element when a new one is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an ASP .NET project and I have a navbar along the side of the page.

```
<div class="navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Home", null, null)</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Marketing", "Marketing", "Home", null, null)</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sales Overview", "SalesOverview", "Home", null, null)</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The active element is the first one of course. On the navbar, this means that that particular selection is slightly darker than the rest. When I click on a different selection in the `navbar`, however, that remains the active action. I'm fairly new to html and the solution that comes to mind for me is to assign each `<li>` an `id` and `onclick` then write some javascript to change the class of that id to active whenever it is clicked.

This seems like a roundabout way to do something that should be included within the `<ul>`. So my question is whether there is a simpler way to do this that scales better (here meaning, I may potentially add way more things to the navbar, I don't want an onclick method for each).

The above code is in `Shared/~Layout`, by the way, so not as simple as defining separate but similar views for each of the pages, this view needs to actually get updated somehow.

Comment: is jquery accepted or plain js only?

Comment: jquery is fine, however like I said, solution should be easily scalable for arbitrary amount of `<li>` elements

Comment: Could you use onBlur and onFocus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a very simple and not too difficult to scale solution. Within each of the `Controller` methods referenced by the action link I would have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ViewBag.Index="active";
     return View();
}
```

Similarly for all of the other ones. Then in the view:

```
<li class=@ViewBag.Index>...
<li class=@ViewBag.Marketing>...
```

Since all of the other ones are empty strings, no class is assigned except to the one.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery,then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $lis=$('.nav li');
    $lis.click(function(){
        $lis.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**// Update**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pathname = window.location.pathname;        
var $lis=$('.nav li');
        $lis.click(function(){
           $this = $(this);
            if (pathname == $this.find('a').attr('href')) {
                $lis.removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: The `active` state changes, but only for a brief duration before returning `active` to default `<li>`

Comment: Does your page reloads?
Try using return false at the end in click function.

Comment: This code does however, override the Html.ActionLink from executing. Is there a way for both the onclick here and the ActionLink to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `BootstrapSupport.HtmlHelperExtensions` which includes the following helper extension to handle menu links.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
{
    var currentAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
    {
        InnerHtml = helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString()
    };
    if (controllerName == currentController && actionName == currentAction)
    {
        builder.AddCssClass("active");
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

This makes my menu like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @Html.MenuLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
        @Html.MenuLink("Schedule", "Schedule", "Home")
        <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
        @Html.MenuLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin")
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still need it you can use jQuery to do it

```
var list = $('.nav li');
list.change(function(){
    list.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
});
```